# AZCopy returning error because of the Source Folder

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I have the following PowerShell script to copy a folders contents up to an Azure Storage Container.

I'm trying to get it working, but I keep getting an error back saying:

```
[2019/05/13 17:32:31][ERROR] The syntax of the command is incorrect. Error parsing the argument "C:\temp": parameter name is required.
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
$azPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"
Set-Location $azPath

$StorageAccountName = "#"
$StorageAccountKey = "#"
$ContainerName = "#"

$SourceFolder = "C:\temp"
$DestURL = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$ContainerName"
$Result = .\AzCopy.exe $SourceFolder $DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y
$Result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add parameters `/source` and `/dest`, this should be `$Result = .\AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y`

[image]